# Que signifie l'expression « les faits de surface » ?

Tags: sens, expressions

Que signifie l'expression « les faits de surface » dans ce contexte ?

> Il y avait dans notre société une bipolarisation culturelle dont les deux termes sont le pôle de la culture savante, et le pôle de la culture folklorique. Une analyse qui s’en tient aux faits de surface montre que les rapports entre les deux pôles ne sont pas conflictuels.

Answer (score 5):

*Une analyse qui s’en tient aux faits de surface* signifie tout simplement *une analyse superficielle*, qui se contente donc de ce qui est visible, sans chercher à approfondir.

On peut donc supposer qu'une observation plus poussée montrera que les rapports peuvent être conflictuels entre les deux pôles en question, celui de la culture savante et celui de la culture folklorique.

Answer (score -1):

Les faits de surface sont les états de chose relativement palpables dans la société, comme les statuts qui existent dans les diverses institutions, comme les actions individuelles ou les actions de groupes, comme les courants de pensée universellement reconnus dans la société et largement publiés. Ce que l'on exclura de ces faits de surface sont les problèmes de réconciliation entre d'une part les croyances et les habitudes folkloriques et d'une autre les connaissances scientifiques et autres connaissances issues d'un progrès récent, et les adaptations à la vie qui en découlent, problèmes reconnus auxquels peuvent souvent n'être donnés qu'une importance académique, problèmes qui n'ont une réalité que pour la partie la plus informée de la population et qui ne se traduisent pas par des conflits en raison de causes variées dont l'une est la nécessité où l'apparente impossibilité de plier l'aspect traditionnel des choses au mode de pensée que force le progrès.

On pourra donc, par exemple constater qu'une loi établie sur la base de coutumes folkloriques n'est pas un sujet de discorde quand considérée sur le plan de notions  internationales modernes de droits humains.