# Que signifie l’expression « la surface de l’existence » dans ce contexte?

Tags: sens, expressions

Bonjour à tous. Est ce que l’expression « la surface de l’existence » veut dire «l'apparence des faits» dans ce contexte :
« On ne peut plus d’une manière moraliste approcher la vie sociale et culturelle de
la société marocaine à partir d’une dichotomie, quelle qu’elle soit : vrai/faux, bien/mal, traditionnel/moderne, local/universel, etc. D’une part, la surface de l’existence permet un constat des plus pertinents : le signe fait sens, le signe devient signification. »? Merci d’avance.

Comment: J'ai demandé l’interprétation d'une seule phrase (la surface de l’existence) pas le texte dans sa totalité qui sert seulement à indiquer le contexte dans lequel se trouve la phrase. Peut être je me suis mal exprimé.

Comment: C'est une question qui porte plus sur la philosophie que sur la langue française.

Comment: Merci pour cette remarque Teleporting Goat

Answer (score 3):

Cela ne signifie pas grand'chose, sauf que l'auteur de ce texte est un jargonneur incorrigible. Si c'était poétique, on pourrait le sauver, si c'était érudit on pourrait le peser, mais très franchement cette surface est pédante et finalement impropre.

Answer (score 1):

Il en est du terme « surface de l'existence » comme pour de nombreux autres tels que « étendue de l'existence », « profondeur de l'existence », « publicité de l'existence », « matérialité de l'existence », « spiritualité de l'existence », … ; ce sont des termes, quel que soit le domaine où on les trouve, (sociologie, politique, philosophie, …), qui nécessitent le plus souvent une introduction les définissant de façon plus ou moins explicite (dans une phrase ou un paragraphe qui précède, ou dans un autre ouvrage et dans ce cas on peut même les citer par des références,  par exemple de la sorte de « ce que untel appelle la publicité de l'existence »). Si l'auteur ne fournit pas ces définitions on est en droit de dire qu'il est, pour le moins, difficile à lire, et avec moins d'indulgence, qu'il écrit de manière opaque.

Si on se réfère à cette autre question que vous posez ([ref](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/37198/17649)), on trouve encore le mot « surface » dans ce qui vous cause un problème, l'expression est cette fois « faits de surface »  (terme auquel je donne une explication à ma façon dans votre question) ; donc en supposant que cette nouvelle question appartienne au même sujet (ce qui est probable), il est évident que l'on pourrait rapporter cette idée de surface à celle de faits de surface et (pourquoi pas ?) comprendre « faits de surface de l'existence » ; la vérification de cette possibilité est peut être faisable dans une relecture attentionnée des pages concernées en gardant à l'esprit le rapprochement que je suggère.